# Как передать массив JS в запрос PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Есть массив строк :

```
let arr = ['Amsterdam','Rome','Berlin','London','Paris'] ;
```

и есть запрос  php :

```
    $url = file_get_contents('http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=707dee63a73b4df5af152654210704&q=
['Место,куда нужно по очереди вставить элементы нашего массива'],[long]&days=2')
```

Каким образом это можно ? буду рад любой помощи

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Comment: @AlexeyTen там что то есть про кодирование массива в get-параметр?

Comment: Там есть про то, что PHP и JS вообще живут в разных мирах и для начала нужно передать массив из JS в PHP. А уж на писать на PHP цикл я думаю автор справится. Хотя не уверен

Answer (score 0):

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Подробнее тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468459/sending-a-json-to-server-and-retrieving-a-json-in-return-without-jquery